# bootstrap responsive dropdown not "padding"

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that when i minimize the screen to 'tablet mode' it properly created a collapse icon, however the sub menus (dropdown-menu) does not pad or make itself present, it just overflows over the existing stuff, and the menus at the very bottom altogether do not display. any help would be appreciated, here is my code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-advanced" id="advanced-menu">
    <div class="navbar-inner"> <span class="visible-tablet">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">

          <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_global_cfg" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                Captive Portal<b class="caret"></b></a> 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_global_cfg">Global Configuration</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_inst_cfg">Instance Configuration</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_vap_cfg">VAP Configuration</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_upload_bin">Upload Binary Files</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_web_custom">Web Customization</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_web_preview">Web Customization Preview</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_local_user">Local Users</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_local_group">Local Groups</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_auth_client">Authenticated Clients</a>

                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="/admin.cgi?action=cp_fail_client">Failed Authentication Clients</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your code but it is still hard to see what is happening. Could you share an example or make one using http://www.bootply.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 2 or 3?  Your HTML looks like Bootstrap 2.